# How to generayte integrate grcode in php

Tags: php

I am currently enhancing a php application to use qrcode which can be scanned and do other processes. The requirement is that the qr code must contain a logo at the middle (its center). I am able to generate the qr code using qrlib library but i have not been able to embed the logo at the center, probably because i don't see its documentation on how to do that.

With qrlib i just had to include the library and call it and it generated the qrcode as follows

`include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');`
`QRcode::png('Take care, COVID-19 is for real');`

I have done it using the simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode in laravel but with procedural php i am a bit stranded

I need an assistance on how I can embed the logo using the same or a different library

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520988/creating-a-qr-code-with-a-centered-logo-in-php-with-php-qr-code-generator

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply with a JavaScript library from this link https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/. instead of going through PHP

example:

```
// simple method :

<div id="qrcode"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "your-link-here e.g https://example.com");
</script>

// or more advanced method :
<script>
var qrcode = new QRCode("test", {
    text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});

qrcode.clear(); // clear the code.
qrcode.makeCode("http://naver.com"); // make another code.

</script>
```

for more details including download check here:
https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

to add a logo or embed logo with your qrcode you can use qart.js

check out this example: https://kciter.so/qart.js/

Comment: The requirement is that the qr code must contain a logo at the middle (its center).

Comment: Thanks @Antony, i just checked the details, can't find how i can embed a logo at the center of the qr code,can you assist me on how to achieve that??

Comment: try using qart js instead od qrcodejs the example is in this link : https://kciter.so/qart.js/